# eval() function in php

Tags: php, eval

here is a code where I don't understand why the php code where the output is: This is a $string with my $name in it. This is a cup with my coffee in it.

```
<?php
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';

$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';

// will not echo the value of the strings variable because there in ' '
echo $str. "\n";

// this function is like writing the php code outside of it
// it gets a string with php statments (;) 
// because the code is written in a string
// if it is written it double quotes you have to escape $ and " 
// and if it is written in single quotes you have to escape '

eval("\$str = \"$str\";");

//it is not like this, why?????
//eval('$str = "$str";');

// and not like this, why???????
//$str = "$str" ;

echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

why doesn't the statement : eval('$str = "$str";'); or the statement: $str = "$str" ; do the same thing as the statement: eval("\$str = \"$str\";"); in this code

Comment: PHP Manual says... `Caution
The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.`

Comment: `$str = "$str"` is only assigning the value to the variable that it already has, it does not evaluate its contents for any kind of PHP syntax.

Answer (score 2):

A Double quoted string evaluates all the variables inside it. A Single Quoted String does not.

Now to this statement

```
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
```

first `\$str` -> the $ is escaped, so its a literal, and not the `$str` variable

second `$str` -> the $ is not escaped and the whole string is in double quotes, so this will become

`$str = "This is a $string with my $name in it."`

Now this PHP code is evaluated, which assigns the string on right to the variable on left. Hence `$str` becomes what `This is a cup with my coffee in it`.

Eval should be avoided.

Comment: doesn't the string that is written in the eval function are statements between php tags? hence, the statement that is written as a string: ("\$str = \"$str\";"); isn't like writing this statement between php tags: $str = "$str" ???

Answer (score 0):

```
//it is not like this, why?????
//eval('$str = "$str";');
```

Because the input string might contain single quotes, so you can't use them to start and end the string.

```
// and not like this, why???????
//$str = "$str" ;
```

Because you want to evaluate a string, and the above is no string.

I don't see the point of this example, just use double quotes:

```
<?php
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';

$str = "This is a $string with my $name in it.";

echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need `eval` in this context ?

Variables inside single quotes will not be interpreted , Instead put it under double quotes.

```
$str = "This is a $string with my $name in it."; //<--- Replaced single quotes to double quotes.
```

Secondly.. If you are really worried about escaping why don't you make use of a **`HEREDOC`** Syntax

```
<?php
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';

$cont=<<<ANYCONTENT
This is a $string with my $name in it. This text can contain single quotes like this ' and also double quotes " too.

ANYCONTENT;

echo $cont;
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
This is a cup with my coffee in it. This text can contain single quotes like this ' and also double quotes " too.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first eval statement:

```
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
```

As second $ is not escaped, and you are using double quotes over the entire arguement, so second $str's value is passed to the eval, and the argument of eval becomes:

```
eval("\$str = \"This is a $string with my $name in it.\";");
```

which when evaluated, becomes:

```
$str = "This is a $string with my $name in it.";
```

Which assigns 'This is a cup with my coffee in it.' to $str.

In the second eval:

```
eval('$str = "$str";');
```

the statement evaluated is:

```
$str = "$str";
```

Which is same as your third statement. When this statement is executed, it converts non-strings to strings. In this case, $str is already a string, so this statement has no effect on the value of $str.

Hope this helps. :)